# How to test the application in Incognito mode using puppetter?

Tags: puppeteer, jest-puppeteer

> When ever I tried using the below code, it launches a second window in incognito mode.

```
const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
const page = await context.newPage();
```

> When I tried the below code, it launches the Incognito mode. But opens the url in regular chrome mode

```
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
    headless: false,
    args: [
          "--incognito"
    ]
});
```

Comment: I get an incognito window with your code.

Comment: Incognito will be opened. But it is getting  launched as a second window .

Comment: What would be the problem with that? (honest question)

Comment: Yes , Eg:- when clicking a link inside a webpage, it opens as a popup window/new window, then it will be difficult to handle.